# Routing to a subdirectory in Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I am just getting started with RoR and have a basic question.

Currently I am creating simple static_pages e.g. about contact etc, for my application that will route as follow:

```
root "static_pages#home"
match "/about",   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
match "/contact", to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

Which will look as follows:

- localhost:3000/about
- localhost:3000/contact

Now I would to create a sub directory called "legal" with an index page for the directory and other some pages, which will look like:

- localhost:3000/legal
- localhost3000:/legal/terms

Would I need to create a new controller to do this and include all the action or is there a way I can do this with my "StaticPages" controller some how?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
  scope '/legal' do
    match "/about",   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
    match "/contact", to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
  end
```

For more info check out the guides for namespacing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing